# Embedding python program in a GTK application (in C)

Tags: python, c, user-interface

I am writing a GTK+ GUI (C language) application , i have previously rapidly developed a pygtk GUI application that performs certain tasks. Now, instead of rewriting the whole Pygtk GUI and its computational routines back in C and GTK+, i was hope to just push a button in C GUI and lauch the python GUI.

In an initial attempt, i tried to just call the python GUI from a C code, but it crashed in run-time, it complained about GTK imports and segmentation fault.

Note, that the Python GUI standalone application works fine ( the name of the standalone file is FPG.py).

So how does one efficiently import modules and libraries from python into C/C++

Here is what i did :

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
 Py_Initialize();

 FILE *fp      = fopen ("FPG.py",   "r+");
 PyRun_SimpleString("#!/usr/bin/python2.7");
 PyRun_SimpleString("import sys ");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from scipy.integrate import odeint ");
 PyRun_SimpleString("import math ");
 PyRun_SimpleString("import csv ");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from decimal import *");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from math import pi ");
 PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy as np");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from datetime import datetime");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from time import mktime ");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio");
 PyRun_SimpleString("import os");


 PyRun_SimpleString("from datetime import datetime");
 PyRun_SimpleString("from time import mktime");

 // the actual file  
 PyRun_SimpleFile(fp,"FPG.py");
 Py_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

I compiled the program as follow (i know it's C++ compiler) :

```
g++ $(python-config --cflags) -o simple $(python-config --ldflags) ./simple.cpp
```

This program even though it compiles , at run-time crashes with the following excerpt of the output executable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 68, in load_module
    dynamic_module._load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 291, in _load
    overrides_modules = __import__('gi.overrides', fromlist=[self._namespace])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1502, in <module>
    initialized, argv = Gtk.init_check(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_cascade_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion `GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion `GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion `rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion `GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion `GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion `rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:25913): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion `rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed


.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You typed `mport numpy as np` missed an `i`. Also you must import `sys` module for `argv`.

Comment: Thanks iharob , but i don't think that it the problem, i fixed what you suggested, but still have all these Gtk-Critical problems and a segmentation fault core dump at the end.

Comment: You did not mention the segmentation fault, another thing why do you use C++ gtk is a C library and libpython.so is also a C library. Gtk-Critical problems are not really so severe. Any change you are running the program as root?

Comment: I don't know if version 3 of gtk requires a `gtk_init()` call, but version 2 does, and perhaps the gtk errors are related to that.

Comment: I actually have it initialized gtk_init() no doubt. i did read somewhere that when one has "from <Module> import <submodule>" it will have problem, but all the errors are Gtk based initialization erros

Comment: Are you running the program as root?